# Highlight tags which is not available into the list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tag-it

I am using jQuery UI widget [Tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) in `Asp.net`. Code is working fine but i want to highlight the tags which is not available into the list.

if my tags are

`var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript']`

and i am using any other word which is not available into `sampleTags` how do i highlight these tags with other color.

I am using the following code

**JS:-**

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="../CSS/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
          <script src="../JavaScript/tag-it.js"></script>
        <link href="../CSS/tagit.ui-zendesk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UpdateSingImgKwds.aspx/GetKeywords',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {
                $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
                    caseSensitive: false,
                    availableTags: res.d,
                    allowSpaces: true,
                    singleField: true,
                    singleFieldNode: $('#txtCompKwds'),
                    beforeTagAdded: function (event, ui) {

                        if ((res.d).indexOf(ui.tagLabel.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                            $(ui.tag).css('background', '#fff1b5')
                        }
                    }

                });

            },
            failure: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });


    });
```

**CS code :-**

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string[] GetKeywords()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        string queryString = "select * from KWD_Library ORDER BY Keyword asc";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vConnString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lst.Add(reader["Keyword"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lst.ToArray();
```

Please help me to do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`beforeTagAdded`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#beforetagadded-function-callback)** event and compare the tags added to `sampleTags`,

```
beforeTagAdded: function (event, ui) {             
        if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel,sampleTags) == -1) {
            $(ui.tag).css('background', 'red')
            //you can use `addClass()` here instead of .css()
        }
    }
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/5/)**

---

```
$("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    beforeTagAdded: function (event, ui) {             
        if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel,sampleTags) == -1) {
            $(ui.tag).css('background', 'red')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine but if the values of ` <input name="tags" id="mySingleFieldTags" value="sony,hp,Dell">` Already exist then its not working .. for that any solution ?

Comment: it's a `List<string>`

Comment: Sir when the input values are empty then its working fine... is any other way to achieve this ???

Comment: Sir where do I put the line `console.log(sampleTags)` ??

Comment: If i write 'php' to 'Php' it changed the color

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()` -- `sampleTags.indexOf(ui.tagLabel.toLowerCase()`

Comment: The Problem is some fields are Lower case and some are upper. is it works for both ?

Comment: Any other way to convert it on run time ?? @Shaunak D

Comment: Can you paste your ajax code in the question? And also what `res.d` contains.

Comment: Hello Sir ...I am in trouble in tags  please help me if you have time

Comment: if the length of array list is Up-to 7345 its getting error `resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` in browser @Shaunak D

Comment: Not sure about this. There might be memory limit.

Comment: Is there any other method to add words without using `List<string> lst = new List<string>()` in code behind

Comment: You can use plain string array `string arr[]`

Comment: And how do i add values in `string arr[]` ??

Comment: Stuck with issue Sir ..I need your help @Shaunak D

Comment: `arr.add("string")` to add one element

Comment: Check google for string array. Or keep your list and return `lst.ToArray()`. If this does not solve. Ask a new question on SO. someone might know the correct answer.

Comment: Okay Sir :) i will ask a new question